# Dictionary in Attribute workaround

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a REST Web Api endpoint, which can receive query parameters.

Some of these query parameters are used to generate a LINQ expression with the inner model's properties. For instance:

```
http://api.example.com/scenes?episode=32
```

The query parameter `episode` generates a LINQ expression:

```
s => s.Episode == 32
```

Which property to use for the comparison is specified in an attribute that each query parameter has:

```
public class SceneQueryData
{
     [PropertyFilter("Episode")]
     public int? Episode { get; set; }
}
```

I am saying: `"Hey, use this "episode" query parameter as a filter for the "Episode" property of the model"`.

Now, the generated expression is a simple equality comparison (`=`), so I'm in need of more complex operations (`<, <=, >, >=`), for that I can set an additional member in the attribute:

```
[PropertyFilter("Episode", QueryOperations = new Dictionary<string, QueryOperation>()
{
    { "le", QueryOperation.LessThanOrEquals },
    { "lt", QueryOperation.LessThan },
    { "ge", QueryOperation.GreaterThanOrEquals },
    { "gt", QueryOperation.GreaterThan }
}]
```

This will allow me to make queries such as `scenes?episode.le=20`, which would be translated to

```
e => e.Episode <= 20.
```

However, I cannot pass in a dictionary as an attribute argument, so I need another way to accomplish this **using attributes**.

Comment: You could define the mapping from string to operation statically, and just pass the list of allowed operations/strings to the attribute?

Comment: @Blorgbeard I thought of that, but what if each property wants to have a different string -> operation mapping?

Comment: Well, do they? You're writing the code.. It seems unlikely to be necessary to me, on the face of it.

Answer (score 0):

Define a separate attribute (say, OperationAttribute) with AttributeUsage such that AllowMultiple = true.  Then specify each key-value pair that you would have put in the dictionary with a separate OperationAttribute.  Like so:

```
[AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class OperationAttribute : Attribute 
{
    public OperationAttribute(string name, QueryOperation op)
    {
        ...etc...
    }
}

public class SceneQueryData
{
    [PropertyFilter("Episode")]
    [Operation("le", QueryOperation.LessThanOrEquals)]
    [Operation("lt", QueryOperation.LessThan)]
    [Operation("ge", QueryOperation.GreaterThanOrEquals)]
    [Operation("gt", QueryOperation.GreaterThan)]
    public int? Episode { get; set; }
}
```